# Falta una letra en el último campo de formulario React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formularios, usestate, useeffect

Tengo un formulario hecho en react, con objetos en el useState que es donde se cargan los datos del formulario, adicionalmente tengo useEffect para validar el email, usuario, cedula, etc.  y me llama la atencion que en el último dato que introduzco (ejemplo la dirección) , al enviar el objeto y revisar la información, me hace falta la última letra del último campo introducido... a qué se deberá eso? y cómo se puede solucionar.  Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo, sin muestras de lo que hiciste y sin que los demas puedan reproducir tu error, es imposible saber donde esta tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.